# Custom validation error parameters

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I've made a custom validator in my Laravel application, and I want to make a custom error. Ideally, this will be *Your image must be at least 500 by 500 pixels*.

However, I cannot figure out how to get the parameters (500, 500) in the *validation.php* file.

This is the current error message:

```
"image_dimensions" => "Your :attribute must be at least GET PARAMETERS HERE",
```

Here's the validator:

```
Validator::extend('image_dimensions', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

    $image = Image::make($value);

    $min_width = $parameters[0];
    $min_height = $parameters[1];

    if ($image->getWidth() < $min_width) {
        return false;
    } else if ($image->getHeight() < $min_height) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

});
```

And here I am using it:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array(
        'image' => Input::file('file'),
    ),
    array(
        'image' => 'image_dimensions:500,500'
    )
);
```

How do I fetch the parameters given in my error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add replacers to your message, for example :myMin and :myMax

```
"image_dimensions" => "Your :attribute must be at least :myMin to :myMax",
```

Add replacer to your rule

```
Validator::replacer('image_dimensions', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return str_replace(array(':myMin', ':myMax'), $parameters, $message);
});
```

If you are extend the Validator, you can add replace method for your rule:

```
class CustomValidator extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

    public function validateFoo($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        return $value == 'foo';
    }

    protected function replaceFoo($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        return str_replace(':foo', $parameters[0], $message);
    }

}
```

For more information read [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)